# mac file authority not right with umask

Tags: macos, unix, authorization

[enter image description here][1]I was learning the linux, and I know the authority of file with user group and others.

I used `umask` command on my mac to check my file authority, it shows 022, but when i touch a file and use the `ll` command and it shows nobody have the the execute authority.

I searched my book, and search the google, but I find it hard to describe this problem, can anybody give me an explanation?

Comment: What you describe is perfectly consistent with what umask does. First, make sure you actually know [how `umask` works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). It makes sense that a _file_ would not be executable just by touching it. Only _executable_ files would have the execute bit, and that's usually set explicitly after writing an executable file.

Comment: @JamesBucanek well, I just search some book and I realized that a newly created file was not set executable by default. so i confused it, Thank u very much!